# Compass compile results in undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

When I try to run the compile command below for compass I get an error saying `sub` is undefined for `nil:Nilclass`.

**Command**

```
compass compile hack-stack/app/styles --relative-assets --sass-dir hack-stack/app/styles --output-style expanded --images-dir images --css-dir public
```

**Error**

```
compass-0.12.6/lib/compass/compiler.rb: undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm running ruby version 2.0.0p0 and compass version 0.12.6.

What is wrong with the command I'm running?

Comment: What version of Sass are you using? Have you tried updating to the current stable version of Ruby (v2.1.2)?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7 (Maptastic Maple) and Compass 0.12.6 (Alnilam). I just updated to 2.1.2. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need the compass pre-release.

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Comment: Still no luck with that.

Comment: Remove all versions of compass and install it again. you may need to use sudo.